# Apple Development: add UDID to provisioning profile without Apple development membership?

Tags: ios, xcode, diawi

I'm trying to use Diawi to distribute my test iOS app within my team and Diawi gave me "unable to download" error. I'm aware that I have to add the other members device's UDID into my provisioning profile.

However, I have not enroll in Apple Dev Program since it's 99$/Year. So is there any alternative to which I can distribute my app without spending 99$?

Comment: No there is no other alternative to distribute ios apps.

Comment: That sucks. It's frustrating after distributing an Android app to other people. Thank you for the reply.